# jQuery and javascript dealing with xhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to run this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table").append("<tr>");
for(var i=1, i<7, i++){
$("table").append("<td>"+i+"</td>");
}
$("table").append("</tr>");
})
```

which means i want to add a row and 7 table data to my row and close the row, for this im using a "for", as it should b used with javascript.

This is an external .js file and is throwing me an error;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, this is in the third line, the comparison operator "<". but then, how can i use for if i cna't use the comparison operators!!!!, also it will throw an error for ++. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your script, need to use `;` instead of `,` to define 3 sections of `for(var i=1; i<7; i++)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //generate a string 
    var str = "<tr>");

    //Here you need to use ; instead of ,
    for(var i=1; i<7; i++){
        str += "<td>"+i+"</td>";
    }

    str += "</tr>";

    //Append
    $("table").append(str);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `;` instead of `,`cinside for loop

You need to append `td` to `tr`.

Append will add the whole element(its working is not like string concatenation). So you dont need to add the `<tr>` and then `</tr>` separately.

```
$("table").append("<tr></tr>");
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    $("table tr").append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/113/)

Comment: Thx a lot it was driving me crazy, I need more coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `;`, not `,`.Use this `for(var i=1; i<7; i++)`